# Firebase Send Cloud Message to Android App Topics via POST Request - Google Oauth Playground Access Token Expiration

Tags: php, android, firebase, api, firebase-cloud-messaging

**Background**
I am trying to implement push notifications in my android app via topics(My target users are 5K+ at a time). For the said purpose, I am using firebase cloud messaging.

My android app is set up with firebase and I can successfully send push notifications (Firebase Cloud Messaging) via the Firebase web console. (this is the testing phase)

To make things user-friendly, I want to utilize Firebase API and intend to develop a web console (PHP-based) from where these notifications can be sent. I need to call the firebase API routes from there.

Currently, I am testing the Firebase API route with POSTMAN that sends the notification messages.

The API request is authenticated and it needs two authentication parameters

1. Server Key that is fetched from Firebase project and is sent in the header.
2. Authorization Bearer is ‘Access Token’ created from Google Oauth Playground ([https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/][1])

I have successfully authenticated the API request and notifications are successfully sent from POSTMAN as well.

**Problem**
The Authorization Bearer usually called ‘Access Token’ created from Google Oauth Playground has a very short expiration time (5 mins). The access token can have at max 60 mins expiration time.

**POST Request URL**
https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/fir-notificationsdemo-6996c/messages:send

**Header**
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer ya29.ElqKBGN2Ri_Uz...HnS_uNreA

**body (json)**

```
{
 "message" :{
      "topic": "employees",
            "notification" : {
                "title": "Notification: Title of Your Notification",
                "body" : "Notification: Body of Your Notification" , 
                "image": "image url here"              
            }
  } 
}
```

**Here is the respective PHP Curl for that POST request**

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/fir-notificationsdemo-6996c/messages:send',
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>'{
 "message" :{
      "topic": "employees",
            "notification" : {
                "title": "Notification: Title of Your Notification",
                "body" : "Notification: Body of Your Notification" , 
                "image": "https://www.imageurl.goeshere/media/2020/10/07.jpg"              
            }
  } 
}',
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Authorization: Bearer ya29.a0AfH6SMBB.......e8-3'
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
echo $response;
```

Oauth Playground also provides a refresh token along with access token.
I need to device a mechanism when access token is expired, refresh token is used to get a new token.
OR if there is any other way to do this.

Thank you

**P.S:** I am not using the Firebase legacy API instead I am using the preferred one Firebase HTTP v1 API. Oauth Access Token is not required for legacy API.
[1]: https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/

Answer (score 0):

I found EdwinHoksberg php-fcm repository on Github that served the purpose.
Github repo link: [EdwinHoksberg PHP FCM Github Repository](https://github.com/EdwinHoksberg/php-fcm/blob/master/docs/quickstart.rst)
Documentation: [Quick Start Documentation](https://php-fcm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html)

There are many other similar repositories on GitHub which serve the purpose but this one is with comprehensive documentation.

Although it is mentioned that it uses HTTP v1 instead of legacy API but oauth access key is not required for this repo.